How can I remove / avoid scientific notation in postresql
I am calculating price_per_kg, which I need to round to 2 decimal places.
I am using PostreSQL 13.0. Given weight is in grams, that's why * 1000
The problem is, that I am getting result in form of scientific notation, instead of decimal number.
this is my code:
SELECT
    ROUND((((price/weight)*1000)::numeric), 2) AS price_per_kg
FROM 
    table

Expected result:
0.29
9938.0

But getting:
0.29e0
0.9938e4


What is the data type of price and weight?

@Bohemian - both price and weight are double precision

I can't reproduce this.  Maybe it is your client which has decided how to format this data, not the database. What if you explicitly caste to text inside the database, ROUND((((price/weight)*1000)::numeric), 2)::text

Your code works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/7ECrX5Fe .  It's probably the way your query result display code/tool works, not the query

To make it working correctly, I had to do this change: ROUND((((price/weight)*1000)::numeric), 2)::float AS price_per_kg

This is your client. The only way that Postgres would do that is using something like select to_char(0.00100000000000000000, '9.9999EEEE'); 1.0000e-03
